# C# SELECT GROUP by SUM LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have some tables which i am joining with LINQ, this is one of the first times using it so im not that familiar with it.

The next query is as:

```
var query = from catalogoV in catalogo_DT.AsEnumerable() 
            where catalogoV.Field<String>("Incluye GPS") == "yes"
                join vehicle in vehicleData.AsEnumerable()
                     on catalogoV.Field<String>("Numero Economico") equals vehicle.Field<String>("DisplayName")
                join actividad in activityData.AsEnumerable() 
                     on vehicle.Field<Guid>("VehicleId") equals actividad.Field<Guid>("VehicleId")   
                select new {Displayname = catalogoV.Field<String>("Numero Economico"), ID = vehicle.Field<Guid>("VehicleId"), Increment = actividad.Field<Single>("IncrementalDistance") };
```

This is an example of the results i get

```
{ Displayname = "0DNP-625", ID = {651e5858-bc54-4459-a5de-31144eed3374}, Increment = 0.1 }
{ Displayname = "0DNP-625", ID = {651e5858-bc54-4459-a5de-31144eed3374}, Increment = 0.4 }
{ Displayname = "0DNP-625", ID = {651e5858-bc54-4459-a5de-31144eed3374}, Increment = 4.5 }
{ Displayname = "0003-333", ID = {ecb42206-397f-4cff-bf53-4aac8877491c}, Increment = 0.5 }
{ Displayname = "0003-333", ID = {ecb42206-397f-4cff-bf53-4aac8877491c}, Increment = 5.2 }
```

But i really want to get the sum of increment back and not all the rows for it.
such as:

```
{ Displayname = "0003-333", ID = {ecb42206-397f-4cff-bf53-4aac8877491c}, Increment = 5.7 }
{ Displayname = "0DNP-625", ID = {ecb42206-397f-4cff-bf53-4aac8877491c}, Increment = 5.0 }
```

From what i have read i need to place a gorup in my statement but i dont know how i should mix it with my select, and i cant find something like this on the reference [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb397927.aspx)

Comment: First, switch `catalogo_DT` to a strongly typed datatable so you can get rid of this: `catalogoV.Field<String>("Incluye GPS")` whole business.

Comment: it is a typed datatable, i just thought i needed that, ill remove it, thanks

Comment: Definitely use a strongly typed database. Then you'd group by `DisplayName` and sum the `Increment` in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use a group join, rather than just join, for the `actividad` field. Here's how:

```
var query =
    from catalogoV in catalogo_DT.AsEnumerable()
    where catalogoV.Field<String>("Incluye GPS") == "yes"
    join vehicle in vehicleData.AsEnumerable()
        on catalogoV.Field<String>("Numero Economico") equals vehicle.Field<String>("DisplayName")
    join actividad in activityData.AsEnumerable()
        on vehicle.Field<Guid>("VehicleId") equals actividad.Field<Guid>("VehicleId")
        into actividads
    let ID = vehicle.Field<Guid>("VehicleId")
    orderby ID
    select new
    {
        Displayname = catalogoV.Field<String>("Numero Economico"),
        ID,
        Increment = actividads.Sum(x => x.Field<Single>("IncrementalDistance"))
    };
```

I've added ordering as per your comment.

Comment: thanks @enigmativity, that did work!, if i wanted to order by ID where should i place that?

Comment: @pato.llaguno - I've added the ordering to the query.